# Cuando intento migrar de Angular 10 a 11 me sale este Error: angular/core is not a dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, cli, angular11

Hola buen dia compañeros, tengo el siguiente problema al intentar migrar una app de Angular 10 a 11. Antes decirles que estoy usando la version 16 de Node y 13 del cli de Angular. El error es que al intentar actualizar las versiones que dice que el core de Angular no es una dependencia: observen que después de instalar y actualizar a la version 11 del cli me tiran tambien error esas rutas hacia los modulos core, router, ect.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el comando que indica la guia de Angular para pasar de la version 10 a la 11: `npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11`. Si trato de ejecutar por fragmento esa linea de codigo osea primero instalar `npx @angular/cli@11` y luego si actualizo pero esta vez forzando la actualización `npx update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11 --force` me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco mucho si alguien conoce la solución amigos. Dejo aqui el codigo de mi packaje.json:

```html
{
  "name": "store",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "~10.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/material": "^10.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.11",
    "firebase": "^7.19.0",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.2",
    "swiper": "^4.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.11",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Prueba a usar `npm install` antes de ejecutar el comando para actualizar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la captura de tu IDE, no veo en el árbol de directorios que exista `node_modules` lo que explicaría por qué antes del error que señalas aparece el mensaje

> `Found 0 depedencies`

Prueba a ejecutar `npm i` o `npm install` antes de intentar actualizar la versión de Angular

Comment: Pablo me hizo percatar que no tenia el node_module así que hice desde cero el proceso, instale primero npm y luego si actualice npm, sin embargo me apareció el mismo error. Entonces lo que hice fue pasar la versión 8 del npm a la 7 y luego si actualice de version a la 11 con este comando: npx @angular/cli@11 update @angular/material@11 --allow-dirtyy me aparecio el error "package install failed, see above" sin embargo la versión de Angular del proyecto se me actualizo de la 10 a la 11 pero parece que el comando me elimino la carpeta node_modules dejando obsoleto los modulos base de angular. :/

Comment: Por fin lo he solucionado. después de todo lo que hice y que les he mostrado en este post, pues instale la ultima versión de mvm con: "nvm install latest", luego desinstale la versión global que tengo de Angular cli con "npm uninstall -g @angular/cli@number_version" e instale la ultima versión con: "npm install -g @angular/cli@latest". e instale de nuevo "npm i". Al final quede con la versión 17 de node js y version 13 de Angular. Con esto termine de migrar correctamente de Angular 10 a 11 :D. Espero que a alguien más le sirva esto.